# PowerShell stop script when condition is met

Tags: powershell, loops, office365, exchange-server

I can't see to find the key to this problem I'm having.  I believe I'm using the correct loop for this application, however I cannot get the script to stop when the condition of Percent Complete is at 100%.  The Do loop will run forever.

```
Import-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement

Connect-ExchangeOnline

$User = "thomas.smith@mailbox.com"

New-MoveRequest -Identity "$User" -Remote -RemoteHostName "remotemailboxaddress" -TargetDeliveryDomain "targetdomain.mail.onmicrosoft.com" -RemoteCredential (Get-Credential)

Do {Get-MoveRequestStatistics -Identity "$User" -InformationVariable $Mailbox |  Select-Object Displayname, StatusDetail, TotalMailboxSize, PercentComplete | Format-Table Displayname, StatusDetail, TotalMailboxSize, PercentComplete
            Start-Sleep -Seconds 3
    } Until ({Get-MoveRequestStatistics -Identity "$User" -InformationVariable $Mailbox |  Select-Object PercentComplete} -eq 100)


Run Disconnect-ExchangeOnline once completed with migration
Disconnect-ExchangeOnline
```

The output is almost how I'd like it as well.  I would like for it to add a new line instead of recreating the entire table and of course stop once Percent complete hits 100%.  The script will also skip right to Disconnect-Exchange online as well if it is not commented out.

```
DisplayName   StatusDetail        TotalMailboxSize        PercentComplete
-----------   ------------        ----------------        ---------------
SMITH, Thomas WaitingForJobPickup 53.49 KB (54,770 bytes)              95



DisplayName   StatusDetail        TotalMailboxSize        PercentComplete
-----------   ------------        ----------------        ---------------
SMITH, Thomas WaitingForJobPickup 53.49 KB (54,770 bytes)              95



DisplayName   StatusDetail TotalMailboxSize        PercentComplete
-----------   ------------ ----------------        ---------------
SMITH, Thomas ADUpdate     53.49 KB (54,770 bytes)              95



DisplayName   StatusDetail TotalMailboxSize        PercentComplete
-----------   ------------ ----------------        ---------------
SMITH, Thomas Cleanup      53.49 KB (54,770 bytes)              99



DisplayName   StatusDetail TotalMailboxSize        PercentComplete
-----------   ------------ ----------------        ---------------
SMITH, Thomas Completed    53.49 KB (54,770 bytes)             100



DisplayName   StatusDetail TotalMailboxSize        PercentComplete
-----------   ------------ ----------------        ---------------
SMITH, Thomas Completed    53.49 KB (54,770 bytes)             100
```

I've really tried to make it work, differnt loop conditions, tried setting a variable on the Get-MoveRequestStatistics line.  No luck, any ideas?

Comment: The start-sleep is to help slow down the output, 3 seconds seems like a sweet spot for updates.

Comment: I think the issue is the curly brackets in the condition - this is defining a scriptblock, but is not executing the contents.  Try something like this: `(Get-MoveRequestStatistics -Identity "$User" -InformationVariable $Mailbox).PercentComplete -eq 100`

Comment: you have it in a scriptblock, put it in parenthesis. Otherwise it's not being read properly, so this wouldn't work either: `{100} -eq 100`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Select-Object` outputs an *object* which contains the selected properties.
To get the value of a property, use `Select-Object -ExpandProperty PropertyName`, `ForEach-Object PropertyName` or use member access `(Expression).PropertyName`.

You can remove the 2nd `Get-MoveRequestStatistics` call by capturing the output of the first one in a variable. Then the most natural way to get the `PercentComplete` property in the loop condition is to use member access.

```sh
do {
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 3
    $stats = Get-MoveRequestStatistics -Identity "$User" -InformationVariable Mailbox 
    $stats | Format-Table Displayname, StatusDetail, TotalMailboxSize, PercentComplete
}
Until( $stats.PercentComplete -eq 100 )
```

I've also removed the `Select-Object` because it is redundant. You already select which properties to show for the `Format-Table` command.

There was a little mistake: `-InformationVariable $Mailbox`. The variable name must be passed without `$` prefix. Otherwise PowerShell would take the *value* stored in variable `$Mailbox` as the *name* of the variable to assign the information stream to. This is propably not what you intended.

Comment: Wonderful, this work perfectly against a user I had already setup.  Command ran, realized it was complete and self ended the script.  Thank you for the information on the Select-Object!